# Loop headers and give chosen, distinct names to duplicate values

Tags: vba, excel

I have an export sheet that reuses the same column name multiple times. The export is structured in a way that I know which duplicate value applies to which level, but I'm having a hard time looping through the range and updating the values. What's happening is that the code below either sets every single header to the first Case scenario, or nothing at all.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim Cell As Range
Dim lr As String
Dim lrb As Integer

lr = "1st level Close Record"
lrb = 1
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Debug.Print lastCol

For Each Cell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol))
    Select Case Cell.Value = "Close Record"
        Case lrb = 1
            Debug.Print Cell.Value
            Cell.Value = lr
            lr = "2nd Level Close Record"
            lrb = 2
        Case lrb = 2
            Cell.Value = lr
            lr = "3rd Level Close Record"
            lrb = 3
        Case lrb = 3
            Cells.Value = lr
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: *I'm having a hard time* - what exactly is the issue? it's not clear from what you wrote. see [mcve]. ... Are you running this code on the expected sheet? If not, it may fail. Qualify all variables to their parent object. `Cells` to `Worksheets("mySheet").Cells` where mySheet = your sheet name

Comment: also your code does not even compile :( `Dim Cell as String` then you try to use as Range object in For loop

Comment: @Gregory: you have a low acceptance rate of 29%.  So not bothering with you.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks for the heads up--Updated my post and code above. I am running the code on the selected sheet.

Comment: @SMeaden I didn't realize I had been so negligent. I will go back and make that right. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below tested and it works. Pay attention to the logic difference in below versus yours.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim Cell As Range
Dim lr As String
Dim lrb As Integer

lr = "1st level"
lrb = 1
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Debug.Print lastCol

For Each Cell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol))
    Select Case Cell.Value = "Close Record"
        Case True
            Select Case lrb
                Case Is = 1
                    Cell.Value = lr & " " & Cell.Value
                    lr = "2nd Level"
                    lrb = 2
                Case Is = 2
                    Cell.Value = lr & " " & Cell.Value
                    lr = "3rd level"
                    lrb = 3
                Case Is = 3
                    Cell.Value = lr & " " & Cell.Value
            End Select
    End Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I understand the logic behind this: You set Cell as Range, first of all. Then, you nested the Select Case. First it checks if the Cell.Value = "Close Record" is true. If it is, it then begins another select case that checks what lrb is set to and executes the relevant code if lrb is equal to that particular number. Is that right?

Comment: exactly! @Gregory